# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object dbo.durados_UserSocial

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, backand

I'm testing backand platform and got this error

http://localhost:8100/?ionicplatform=ios&error=%7B%22message%22:%22Cannot%20insert%20duplicate%20key%20row%20in%20object%20%27dbo.durados_UserSocial%27%20with%20unique%20index%20%27IX_durados_UserSocial_UserId_Provider%27.%20The%20duplicate%20key%20value%20is%20(387068,%20facebook).%0D%0AThe%20statement%20has%20been%20terminated.%22,%22provider%22:%22facebook%22%7D#/tabs/dashboard

This is a project started from http://market.ionic.io/starters/ionic-backand-with-social according to Getting started mobile.

I couldn't get any match on google

I think it could be because I'm logging in with the same account that I created the app in backand, however, shouldn't it be possible to just make a login instead of try to register it (or whatever it's trying to do)?

This worked with project default keys for facebook.

Comment: can paste here the code that generate this error, what is the api you  are calling, or the network tab

Comment: I have the same error. Code exactly same as in [examples](https://github.com/backand/backand-ionic-social). I changed only configuration section: 
        `BackandProvider.setAppName('***');`
        `BackandProvider.setSignUpToken('***');`
        `BackandProvider.setAnonymousToken('***');`

Comment: Error happens only if login in facebook by owner of facebook app. For other  users it works.

Comment: Please provide step by step description so i can reproduce, please provide any information or code snippet relevant, did u signed up to backand with fb, did u removed the user from the registered user...?

Comment: Trying to signup with fb. Just 1 moment - the user is owner of fb app

Comment: yeah, the problem seems to be only for my user, which is fb app owner, and this.app owner :)

Comment: just to compliment my previous comment. This is vanilla code as stated in the question, I've only changed the credentials and the facebook app (which I created in facebook platform)